# Xamarin.iOS main and background threads not playing nice

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, xamarin.ios, monitor

I will try and keep this short and sweet.
I have this code which is a result of a button being pressed (so its on the main UI thread)

```
MessageCenter.Init();
```

the above method does this (as well as other things)

```
 NS = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:30"), delegate
                {
                    NSObject.InvokeInBackground(() =>
                        {

                            HandleElapsed();

                        });


                });
```

`HandleElapsed();` obtains an exclusive lock on an object using the `Monitor.Enter(obj)` method. mean while the main ui thread also may need to obtain an exclusive lock. (the lock is in place to ensure sqlite data integrity)

when the main UI encounters a lock on the object (i.e its already locked) the entire app just halts (including the background thread)

I should mention the UI may need to get a lock when its told to change its content. `HandleElapsed();` will ask the main UI thread to change its content.

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("ChangeDetail", new NSString("News"));
```

please note the change in contents is completed on the main thread

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread();
```

its seems when the main ui is stuck on a lock... its also doesn't allow the background thread to continue thus the background thread is not able to move on a call to `Monitor.Exit();`

am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I kept the database open throughout. and simply applied the locking mechanism

```
lock(SQLight.Connection)
{
     ...
}
```

this means all my threads uses the same connection but each thread can only interact with the data in turn.

This seems to have achieved what I wanted